# Sharepoint clientcontext access within WCF in Azure Cloud Service

Tags: csom, wcf, azure

I developed a basic WCF service in Azure Cloud Service which works perfectly fine. I then wanted to make it a new item on a SharePoint list. The added code works perfectly when I start it from Visual Studio, but does not work when I publish it to Azure. WCF respondes perfectly well if I remove SharePoint related parts so I am not adding the detail of getrecords() function.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public List<Test> TestXml()
    {
        string siteUrl = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testsc";

        SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in "xxxxxx".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("xxx@xxx.com", passWord);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test List");

        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";

        oListItem.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
        return GetRecords();
    }
```

I reference following libraries if there are of importance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

I wonder if it works fine on the local because the server I run VS also has SharePoint installed on it ? I've added `Microsoft.SharePoint` references manually to the project.

Comment: What is the result returned by WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible that works locally because SharePoint installation is installed on your box.

Make sure that `SharePoint.Client.*` dlls are deployed to Azure. In *Solution Explorer* open *References* folder, right click each DLL you've added and select *Properties*. In *Properties* window make sure *Copy Local* value is set to *True*.

Comment: Hi dstarkowski, Thanks a lot for your answer, it promptly fixed the issue !